# Close GUI without exiting application TCL

Tags: user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

**How do i close the GUI without exiting the script?**

I have a script that runs every 10 minutes and will call a GUI whenever a few variables change in the script, however when i close the GUI, the application is closed too. I tried adding `-command {destroy .}` 
but it does the same thing as the `exit` command in TK, here is my script

```
lappend auto_path "/bin/gui/scripts"
package require scriptgui
monitor /bin/files/folder1 /bin/files/folder2
set i 0
while {i < 1} {
after 600000
script
}
```

the GUI proc is called inside the script proc whenever the variables in the script proc changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the window go away without destroying it (and ending the application) you use `wm withdraw` on the toplevel.

```
# Assuming you're just using the default one
wm withdraw .
```

You can also intercept a request to close a window (via `wm protocol`) and handle that by withdrawing:

```
wm protocol . WM_DELETE_WINDOW {
    wm withdraw .
}
```

However, if you do that make sure you provide some other way to actually have the process exit for real (assuming you're making a normal application); it's frustrating for users to have no way to actually close the program down and make it go away.

Answer (score 0):

You can close the window with the following:

```
if { [info commands wm] != {} } {wm withdraw .}
```

http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/wm.htm#M46

*wm withdraw - make the window completely invisible, not even an icon. Also makes the window manager forget about the window.*